# Not able to install s3cmd offline

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

## We are trying to install s3cmd in off-line mode but we are getting below error.

```
Searching for python-magic
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-magic/
Download error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'python-magic' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for python-magic.
error:Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('python-magic')
===
```

Btw, python-magic-4.24-43.27.1 is already installed in our server but why s3cmd is not detecting it?

Is there any way skip those steps and install s3cmd?

Comment: By off-line mode means what?

Comment: Rather than using `s3cmd`, these days it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into same error on Debian/jessie. I edited setup.py file like so:

```
#install_requires = ["python-dateutil", "python-magic"]
install_requires = ["python-dateutil"]
```

Then do a force install:

```
python setup.py install --force
```

This skips python-magic package and allows the installation to finish.

Answer (score 4):

These commands did work for me

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip

sudo pip install s3cmd
```